# How can I make Bode plot working properly?

Tags: c#, winforms, plot, charts, axes

I work on application for control engineering students. It can draw step and impulse plots, compute transfer function, check if object is stable etc. I want it to draw a Bode plot, and when I try to do it, I just can't set the `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLogarithmic` property to `true`. It catches exceptions and the chart is badly red crossed.

I suppose that this problem is caused by negative values - I plotted it in non-logarithmic scale and values varied from 0 to -200. Is there any way of making it work correctly?

```
      chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLogarithmic = false;
      var series1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series
      {
        ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
      };
      this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 1;
      this.chart1.Series.Add(series1);
      this.chart1.ResetAutoValues();
      for (double i = 1; i < 10; i++) 
      {
        Complex y = TransferFunction.transmitancja_widmowa(i);
        double x = 20 * Math.Log10(y.Magnitude);
        MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
        if (i > 0)  series1.Points.AddXY(i, x);
      }
      chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLogarithmic = true;
      chart1.Invalidate();
```

Loop results:
    `1.1 : -3.44392273685111
1.2 : -3.87389826338729
1.3 : -4.29752280002408
1.4 : -4.71291711058939
1.5 : -5.11883360978875
1.6 : -5.51449997972875
1.7 : -5.89949601325708
1.8 : -6.27365856592733
1.9 : -6.63700925389649
2 : -6.98970004336019
2.1 : -7.3319726510657
2.2 : -7.664128471124
2.3 : -7.98650645445269
2.4 : -8.29946695941636
2.5 : -8.60338006570994
2.6 : -8.89861721258189
2.7 : -9.18554530550274
2.8 : -9.46452265013073
2.9 : -9.73589623427257
3 : -10
3.1 : -10.2571538390134
3.2 : -10.5076631123304
3.3 : -10.7518185461869
3.4 : -10.9898963940118
3.5 : -11.2221587827283
3.6 : -11.4488541828714
3.7 : -11.6702179579026
3.8 : -11.8864729599972
3.9 : -12.0978301484852
4 : -12.3044892137827
4.1 : -12.5066391946324
4.2 : -12.7044590801796
4.3 : -12.8981183911762
4.4 : -13.0877777366472
4.5 : -13.2735893438633
4.6 : -13.4556975605639
4.7 : -13.6342393291718
4.8 : -13.809344633307
4.9 : -13.981136917305
5 : -14.1497334797082
5.1 : -14.3152458418745
5.2 : -14.4777800929462

5.3 : -14.6374372124706
5.4 : -14.7943133719774
5.5 : -14.9485002168009
5.6 : -15.1000851294023
5.7 : -15.2491514753987
5.8 : -15.3957788334531
5.9 : -15.540043210119
6 : -15.6820172406699
6.1 : -15.8217703768841
6.19999999999999 : -15.9593690626917
6.29999999999999 : -16.0948768985328
6.39999999999999 : -16.2283547952152
6.49999999999999 : -16.3598611180083
6.59999999999999 : -16.4894518216567
6.69999999999999 : -16.6171805769466
6.79999999999999 : -16.7430988894148
6.89999999999999 : -16.8672562107454
6.99999999999999 : -16.9897000433602
7.09999999999999 : -17.1104760386703
7.19999999999999 : -17.2296280894249
7.29999999999999 : -17.3471984165568
7.39999999999999 : -17.4632276508995
7.49999999999999 : -17.5777549101192
7.59999999999999 : -17.6908178711822
7.69999999999999 : -17.8024528386535
7.79999999999999 : -17.9126948091027
7.89999999999999 : -18.0215775318696
7.99999999999999 : -18.1291335664285
8.09999999999999 : -18.2353943365686
8.19999999999999 : -18.3403901815947
8.29999999999999 : -18.4441504047382
8.39999999999999 : -18.5467033189533
8.49999999999999 : -18.6480762902615
8.59999999999999 : -18.7482957787972
8.69999999999999 : -18.8473873776963
8.79999999999999 : -18.9453758499575
8.89999999999999 : -19.0422851634008
8.99999999999999 : -19.1381385238372
9.09999999999999 : -19.232958406555
9.19999999999999 : -19.326766586224
9.29999999999998 : -19.4195841653081
9.39999999999998 : -19.5114316010755
9.49999999999998 : -19.6023287312851
9.59999999999998 : -19.6922947986264
9.69999999999998 : -19.7813484739829
9.79999999999998 : -19.8695078785852
9.89999999999998 : -19.9567906051162
9.99999999999998 : -20.0432137378264`

Comment: You need to provide valid (i.e. positive) x-values first, then set IsLogarithmic true. What do you mean by: 'make it work _correctly_' ?

Comment: I did that, I set ChartType to Line, then I had
for(int i=1, i<10000, i++)
{
    Complex y=transferFcn(i);
    double x=20*Math.Log10(y.Magnitude);
    if(x>0)
            Series1.AddPoints(i,x);
}
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLogarithmic=true;

And it keeps catching exception.
To be hones, by working correctly I mean just working.

Comment: Hm. The x-values seem to be correct, i.e. >= 1; can you write out each point before you crash? or step through the loop to see which value throws?

Comment: I think that problem might be that all values are negative and in result plot would be empty, but I try to check it with your method and also I will try plotting Abs(x) rather than x, just to check if this helps.

Comment: So, I checked, all values are negative and plot would be empty, however when I tried plotting Abs(x) it plotted every value at linear X axis, and when it was supposed to change to logarithmic catched exception anyway, telling me that this axis cannot be logarithmic. Exception is catched in System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea.SetDefaultFromIndexesOrData(Axis axis, AxisType axisType).

Comment: by 'values' you mean x (which would be what we usually call y)? the YValues should not matter. The XValues must be >= 1 ( not just positive)..For the code above I would expect i to go from 1 to 10000.

Comment: I goes indeed how it sould (I changed just to 10 values for faster checking), here is the code that I have currently, it plots everything fine in linear X axis setting but crashes with the same exception when it has to change to logarithmic (I posted in main question, comment is too small).

Comment: Hm, I don't know what y is but I see you only check for `if (i > 0)`. anything less than 1 will also throw the exception..

Comment: Even changing to `if(i>1)` doesn't help.

Comment: Sounds weird. Can you add this before you turn on the log.Axis: `foreach(DataPoint dp in series1.Points) Console.WriteLine(dp.XValue + " : " + dp.YValue[0]);`  and post the output?

Comment: I posted again in main question results of your loop for i from 1.1 to 10 with 0.1 step

Comment: Hm, I tested with these data and the result may look a little funny, but no exceptions: [chart](http://www.file-upload.net/download-10648987/FFF442.png.html). I suspect that either you have some strange other setting or that you add an extra point later and crash on it then. for the first: text with a fresh chart control..!